# Python Pandas Where on Date Index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split my dataframe based on a date, which is the index.  My data looks like this:

```
  print(df.head())

  date_time             value   anomaly                         
  2014-11-23 00:00:00   0.414183    0   
  2014-11-23 01:00:00   0.526574    0
  2014-11-23 02:00:00   0.734324    1
```

My code this far:

```
 df_split = df.where(df.index >= '2014-11-23 01:00:00')
```

My desired output would be:

```
  2014-11-23 01:00:00   0.526574    0
  2014-11-23 02:00:00   0.734324    1
```

My error I get is:

```
  ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self
```

Comment: you should be able to to `df_split = df.loc[df.index >= '2014-11-23 01:00:00']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df_split = df[df.index >= '2014-11-23 01:00:00']
print (df_split)
                        value  anomaly
date_time                             
2014-11-23 01:00:00  0.526574        0
2014-11-23 02:00:00  0.734324        1
```

If values in [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) are sorted use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df_split = df.loc['2014-11-23 01:00:00':]
print (df_split)
                        value  anomaly
date_time                             
2014-11-23 01:00:00  0.526574        0
2014-11-23 02:00:00  0.734324        1
```

---

```
df_split = df['2014-11-23 01:00:00':]
print (df_split)
                        value  anomaly
date_time                             
2014-11-23 01:00:00  0.526574        0
2014-11-23 02:00:00  0.734324        1
```